# Groovy Assertion fail though the values are same

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am writing some soap test case and i see the assertion failing. I see the values are, wasn't sure why it is failing though.

Here is the code:-

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;

def scheduledStartDate = context.expand(     '${testcaseschedule#ResponseAsXml#//Results[1]/ResultSet[1]/Row[1]/SCHEDULEDSTARTDATE[1]}' )


DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))

Date date = dateFormat.parse(scheduledStartDate)
long unixTimeStamp = (long)date.getTime()


def scheduledDateTime = context.expand( '${testcase#$.data.scheduledDateTime}' )"

log.info(scheduledStartDate);

log.info(scheduledDateTime);

log.info(unixTimeStamp);

assert  unixTimeStamp==scheduledDateTime:"Test Case failed as the date in DB and from API were not equal";
```

The information that was logged:
Sat Feb 27 20:00:14 EST 2016:INFO:2016-02-28 00:22:52.0
Sat Feb 27 20:00:14 EST 2016:INFO:1456618972000
Sat Feb 27 20:00:14 EST 2016:INFO:1456618972000

Thanks for looking into my query!

Comment: Can you please share the jdbc response that you processing in the very first statement? And it is clear that `unixTimeStamp` is in long format and `scheduledDateTime` is in different format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `scheduledDateTime` is a `String` and `unixTimeStamp` is a `long`. You can convert the `String` to a `long` in order to compare them.

```
long scheduledDateTime = context.expand( '${testcase#$.data.scheduledDateTime}' ).toLong()
```

Hint: `expand()` returns a `String`.